# Express JS routing non ascii

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I need to parse routes like:

```
/symbol//page/2
/symbol/A/page/2
```

So there might be any symbol except special chars `/#?$%&*@$(){}[]` and quotes. But regexp like `[^...]` seems to exclude non ascii chars. And regexp like `[\u0030-\uFFFF]` not matching request:

```
router.get('/:symbol([\u0030-\uFFFF]+)/page/:page$', function(req, res, next) {
```

Comment: Try [a regex part from here](https://regex101.com/r/JONGlF/1) instead of the `[\u0030-\uFFFF]+`

Comment: Can't find out is it works or not for some reason. But for one symbol i solved it just removed "+". Now i need parts with sequences.